# Someone who refines something until it becomes useful

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a description of someone who produces things  and keeps on developing/refining  it until it becomes useful. This can take years.

*Developer* is the best word as it can mean keeps on constantly developing. However the word has been overused to describe everything including property developer which has the connotation of develop once so I am looking for an alternative word.

*Evolver* isn't a word as someone who keeps on evolving would fit.

I am trying to find maybe a word that explains more than just one part of the life cycle of a product i.e. it includes the designing,creating and
I am trying to explain someone who creates something and also keeps on molding it like an idea until it becomes useful and then keeps on working on it afterwards.

If I call him a *builder, producer,creator,maker or manufacturer* it is more in the context of a conveyor belt process where I am more thinking of describing someone who then refining it until it becomes useful.

Almost like a *potter, molder,sculptor* but you can use outside of pottery.

Here are examples where I want to use it

> The scientist keeps on developing his theories on varying subjects throughout his life. In the morning he wakes up and says "I am a "[...]" as a mantra to remind he to not to stray but to keep on refining  his theories for the betterment of mankind.
>
> 99% of ideas fail as people as people don't realize they need to constantly work and refine their ideas instead of not giving up after it gets no uptake initially. They need to learn to become a [...]
>
> iteration 1 of the product should be seen more of a way to test it in the market for flaws and improvement. The process then gets repeated through multiple iterations. The person who continuously creates and refines the product through iterations is called [...]
>
> John dream is to write a best selling books. His English skill is very average. He knows it will take years and years of practice and writing articles and refining ideas for him to get there. John has to take on the ethos of a [...]

If a word like *masterer,perfecter* existed where someone keeps on working on something until it is mastered or perfected.

If have thought of *refiner, crafter, realizer, do'er,craftsman, artisan, entrepeneur, executor,worker* but none really fit the sentences I given above.

Not sure if such words exists in English, so I'd be open if the origin of the word is from some field or language.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to answer itself with this word:

Refiner  REFI'NER, n.

1. One that refines metals or other things.
2. An improver in purity and elegance; as a refiner of language.
3. An inventor of superfluous subtilities; one is who over nice in discrimination, in arguments, reasoning, philosophy, etc.

Definition from: https://av1611.com/kjbp/kjv-dictionary/refine.html

Comment: The poster had obviously never heard Handel’s Messiah. He should. It might fire him up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one single word for all such sentences; nevertheless, there are some simple solutions.

> "I am a *scientist*"
>
> They need to learn to become *patient*.
>
> The person who continuously creates and refines the product through iterations is called *an engineer*.
>
> John has to take on the ethos of a *writer*.

Comment: Please try to elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica - I wrote this a long time ago.  But I think what I was getting at is that there is no one single word for all such sentences; nevertheless, there are some simple solutions.  What I don't know is why I included all those ellipses....

Comment: I see, I commented because [it showed up in the queues](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/356418). ;)